# Why not produce the expected outputs , How do I fix this error?

Tags: c

Requirement:

> Write a program that calculates the total bill of a customer based on
> the prices of the items they bought, then apply a discount to the
> total bill if appropriate and print the final bill amount. Your
> program will accept as input an integer n that represents the number
> of items the customer ordered. Your program will then accept n numbers
> that represent the prices of the items the customer ordered. Find the
> total amount of the customer's bill, then apply the discount based on
> the following rules and print the final bill amount:
>
> 1. If the customer's total is less than 20 JOD but they bought more than 2 items, they will get a 7% discount.
> 2. If the customer's total is more than or equal to 20 JOD, they will get a 10% discount.
> 3. If the customer's total is more than or equal to 20 JOD, and they bought more than 2 items they will get an additional 5% discount.
> 4. For any individual item that costs more than 7 JODs, they will get an additional 1% discount on the total bill.
> 5. The maximum discount any customer can get cannot be more than 50%. In the following sample runs, the first number in the first line
>    represents the number of the items, while the numbers in the second
>    line represent the prices of the items, the number in the third line
>    represents the output of the program. Print the answer to 2 decimal
>    places.

the expected outputs :

```
Run1
1
4.5
4.50
Run2
2
14 1
14.85
Run3
3
5 4 1
9.30
Run4
5
10 21 9 5 5
41.00
```

the outputs :

```
Run1
1
4.5
4.50
Run2
2
14 1
15.00
Run3
3
5 4 1
9.30
Run4
5
10 21 9 5 5
42.50
```

```
int main() {
  int n, i, count = 0;
  float price, total = 0, discount = 0, max_discount = 0;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%f", &price);
    total += price;
  }

  if (price > 7) {
    discount += total * 0.01;
  }
  if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
    if (total < 20)
      discount = 0;
    else
      discount = total * 0.1;
  } else {
    if (total < 20)
      discount = total * 0.07;
    else {
      discount = total * 0.15;
      if (discount > total * 0.5)
        discount = total * 0.5;
    }
  }

  printf("%.2f\n", total - discount);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get more than one discount which add up? Your code does not seem to support that. If you calculate on pen+paper or pocket calculator, do the results agree with the expected output or the output your program gives? Can you come up with any calculation on pen+paper which comes up with the expected result? With the result of your program?

Comment: @Afnan Mohammed, `if(price > 7){` only applies to the last `price` entered.  That does not meet "For any individual item that costs more than 7 JODs, they will get an additional 1% discount on the total bill."

Comment: @Afnan Mohammed, Aside: Why did you code `float` for money instead of `double`?

Comment: For money, both `float` and `double` are not perfect. I recommend `int` or `long int` of smallest coin.

Comment: Where are your `#include`s? They matter. Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Other than the missing  `#include`s your code looks more or less fine and here it works as expected on the 3 different platforms. What is your platform/compiler/OS/IDE/etc. ?

Comment: Add some more code to display some variables such as `printf("%.2f %.2f\n", total, discount);` and/or use your debugger and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    double price, total = 0, discount = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &price);
    
        total += price;
    
        if(price > 7) discount += 0.01;         // 4
    }
  
    if(total < 20) {
        if(n > 2) discount += 0.07;             // 1
    } else {
        discount += 0.1;                        // 2
      
        if(n>2) discount += 0.05;               // 3
    }
  
    discount = discount > 0.5 ? 0.5 : discount; // 5
  
    printf("%.2f\n", total - total * discount);
}
```

I made comments for every line that handles a specific requirement in your question. In requirement 4, your solution has the error that you only look on the price for the first item. You need to do it for every item.